# When adding item to list in flutter, the item does not save in that list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list of users which show in a dropdown in a form which is then submitted, the list is empty, I have made a function which allows users to type a "name" into a TextFormField and it then adds that name to the list, it then appears on the dropdown, but when the page is reloaded the list item has gone.

example:

```html
void savePerson() {
    String newperson = _newPersonController.text;
    _persons.add(newperson);
  }
  
  The function to save string to list
```

```html
List<String> _persons = [
   
  ]; 
  
  The List
```

```html
 TextFormField(
                    controller: _newPersonController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Add New Person',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.local_hospital,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    )),
                    
The TextFormField where the user inserts the name to be added
```

```html
FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          savePerson();
                          setState(() {
                            _newPersonController.clear();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text('Add Person'))
                        
                        
Button code
```

Just to be clear, it ADDS it to the list/dropdown - that works, but my list doesn't seem to be able to save info to it.

I'm fairly new to flutter - sorry for anything obvious.

Comment: Sorry also the button to save the data : 
FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          savePerson();
                          setState(() {
                            _newPersonController.clear();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text('Add Person'))

Comment: Please add button's code to the question.

Comment: What list is empty?

Comment: I have updated the above - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe the logic of the dropdown, and add the setState() when you add the item to the people list

I use this code:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final TextEditingController _newPersonController =
      new TextEditingController();

  List<String> _persons = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButton(
                  items: List.generate(
                      _persons.length,
                      (i) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(_persons[i]),
                          )),
                  onChanged: (_) {}),
              TextFormField(
                  controller: _newPersonController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Add New Person',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.local_hospital,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  )),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    savePerson();
                    setState(() {
                      _newPersonController.clear();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Add Person'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void savePerson() {
    String newperson = _newPersonController.text;
    setState(() {
      _persons.add(newperson);
    });
  }
}
```

Probably can help you

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, but for me it still doesn't save the list for future use, so i want to be able to return to the page and see that "name" I added...

Comment: the setState, only works for objects that are in the same widget, if you want different widgets to work with the same data or to communicate with each other, you have to use a state manager, you can use provider or a singleton